# iOS - Objective C - Can't render pixel with UInt8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to catch an average color from certain image with `CIAreaAverage`.
The catching operation goes well, outputImage from the filter gave me single pixel `CIImage`.

The problem occurs when attempt to catch `RGB` information with `uint8_t`

> "pixel" (uint8_t) always empty (" ").

I'm pretty sure my render context is not `nil`, only `"render"` operation goes wrong.

I have no idea how to catch RGB data out from `CIImage` correctly.

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong but I guess you don't have to pass a pointer to `pixel` to the render to bitmap function because it is already a pointer. Instead: `[con render: average.outputImage toBitmap: pixel rowBytes: 4 bounds: onePixel format: kCIFormatRGBA8]`

Comment: Oh wow , it work.  Thanks alot.  Have a nice day !

Comment: Okay, I am posting this as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pixel` should be passed directly as a parameter to the `render:toBitmap:rowBytes:bounds:format:` function instead of as a pointer.

The correct function call should be:

```
[con render: average.outputImage toBitmap: pixel rowBytes: 4 bounds: onePixel format: kCIFormatRGBA8]
```

`pixel` is already a pointer so by passing a pointer to `pixel`, the memory address that `pixel` points to is changed. Accessing `pixel[0]` afterwards accesses the now potentially invalid memory address, which is why your program crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.